# How to prevent text from going outside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked at several solutions to this question but none of them work for me. I am appending a paragraph to a div and the text goes out of the element. Here is my code. Please help.

CSS:

```
chat-h {
  margin-left: 7px;
  width: 249px;
  background: red;
}

#chat-p {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.msg span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```

and JQuery

```
function appendMsg(user, msg) {
    var $cont = $("#chat-h");
    $cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;
    $cont.append("<p class='msg' id='chat-p'><span>" + user + ":  </span> " + msg + " </p>");
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it does not overflow for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2jvmaLk8/

Comment: have you tried adding a padding inside your div?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`text-overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

```
div {
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Comment: Put up a jsfiddle with your simplified example, and we can work from there.

Comment: Alright it works by doing text-overflow: string; Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `white-space` and `overflow` properties:

```
#chat-p {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap; /* or `pre` */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And (optionally) add hellip at the end of line:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xj8vfh8d/)